# Creating new variables describing the existing index position of a specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I have a data frame in R with a column containing a unique ID and 10 variables which looks like this:

```
    id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  555  2  1 10  3  8  9  5  7  4   6
2  681 10  5  4  8  7  3  6  2  9   1
3 2300  8  5 10  2  3  1  6  9  4   7
```

I want to create variables named `or1` through `or10` which capture the column position of the values 1:10 for each row.

So, for example, in the first row, the number 1 appears in the column named `V2`, so `or1 = 2`. If I managed to do this correctly for the three rows above, I'd get the following:

```
    id or1 or2 or3 or4 or5 or6 or7 or8 or9 or10
1  555  2   1   4   9   7  10   8   5   6    3
2  681 10   8   6   3   2   7   5   4   9    1
3 2300  6   4   5   9   2   7  10   1   8    3
```

I managed to create `or1` using an absurdly long set of if/then statements but I know there is a much better way that probably involves indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does it:

```
> ord <- data.frame(id = dat$id, t(apply(dat[, -1], 1, order)))
    id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  555  2  1  4  9  7 10  8  5  6   3
2  681 10  8  6  3  2  7  5  4  9   1
3 2300  6  4  5  9  2  7 10  1  8   3
```

(In case "id" is not the first column, I would replace `dat[, -1]` with the more robust `dat[!colnames(dat) %in% "id"]`)

Then, to get the column names exactly like you wanted:

```
colnames(ord) <- sub("^X", "or", colnames(ord))
```

Comment: Holy cow that's efficient!  Thanks so much flodel.